# I would like to know how to implement the files generated by OpenAPI Generator in NestJS

Tags: typescript, api, nestjs, openapi, openapi-generator

I generated a file with the OpenAPI generator and tried to import it, but it does not work.

This is My OpenAPI Specification.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Petstore API
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:3000/api
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      summary: List all pets
      operationId: listPets
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of pets
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Find pet by ID
      operationId: getPetById
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: ID of pet to return
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        '404':
          description: Pet not found
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
```

The following command generated the file for NestJS.

```
docker run --rm \
  -v $$PWD/openapi:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
  -i /local/index.yml \
  -g typescript-nestjs \
  -o /output
```

Here is the generated file.

```
.gitignore
.openapi-generator-ignore
README.md
api.module.ts
api/api.ts
api/default.service.ts
configuration.ts
git_push.sh
index.ts
model/models.ts
model/pet.ts
variables.ts
```

I have created a NestJS project, but I have not modified it in any way.
I just ran

```
nest new my-app
```

Imported the output file into the `src` directory of My NestJS project.

I have added dependent libraries.

```
yarn add @nestjs/axios
yarn add axios
```

I have modified the app.module.ts file

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ApiModule } from './api.module';    # ADD
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';  # ADD

@Module({
  imports: [
    ApiModule,  # ADD
    HttpModule  # ADD
],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've accessed it, but I get an error.

```
{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /api/pets","error":"Not Found"}
```

Why??

Comment: Can you show the `ApiController` and `main.ts`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel There is no ApiController.Do I need to make it myself?

Comment: import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

Comment: Looks like generally the generator isn't creating a proper Nest setup. I guess instead of `ApiController` (was guessing on the name) it's just the `AppController`?  Really I just want to see how the `@Controller()` class related to the `/api/pets` route looks. Next time, please edit the question to add the information so that syntax highlighting can be used